# Why Would I Not Enable Chaining?

Tags: apex, bestpractice, performance, design-patterns

The [Apex Design Patterns](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Design_Patterns) is an awesome resource, and I learned many tricks from it. One of my favorites is method chaining, and I quickly developed an axiom:

> Any time you would return `void`, return `this` instead.

It's dead simple to implement, just change:

```
public void myMethod()
{
    // do stuff
}
```

to:

```
public MyClass myMethod()
{
    // do stuff
    return this;
}
```

Does this strategy cause a performance hit? Are there other risks/concerns that give reason to avoid it?

Comment: And the very first Design Pattern is the [Simpleton Pattern](https://sites.google.com/site/steveyegge2/singleton-considered-stupid)...

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This is mostly a matter of preference. Using chaining tends to create more readable code, and can actually reduce CPU/heap memory. For example, consider these two snippets of code:

```
// No chaining
KeyPair kp = new KeyPair();
kp.setKey(key);
kp.setValue(value);
Utils.someMethod(kp);

// Chaining
Utils.someMethod(new KeyPair().setKey(key).setValue(value));
```

With chaining, we've turned four lines of code into just 1, *and* removed a temporary variable that was only used to hold data long enough to set the values. I commonly use this pattern to build custom exceptions that can throw additional information:

```
throw new CustomException().withValue(value);
```

This pattern is more frequently found with classes that have a *ton* of optional parameters where only a few will be set. This can drastically reduce the number of times a single function has to be written. For example, imagine you had a class like this:

```
class SomeClass {
    SomeClass(Object value1) {
        ...
    }
    SomeClass(Object value1, Object value2) {
        ...
    }
    SomeClass(Object value1, Object value2, Object value3) {
        ...
    }
    ...
    SomeClass(Object value1, Object value2, Object value3, Object value4, Object value5, Object value6, Object value7, Object value8, Object value9, Object value10...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

When there's a ton of optional parameters available, mistakes tend to be made. A function that accepts 32 parameters, many of them optional, can be a nightmare to manage. For example, consider these two pieces of code:

```
Utils.someFunction(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 5, null, null, null, null, null, null, 2, null, null, 'Hello World');

Utils.someFunction(new Parameter().setParam9(5).setParam16(2).setParam19('Hello World'));
```

Which one do you think is easier to read? Which is easier to maintain? Not only do you know what values you're assigning, you also get the option to order them any way you want to:

```
Utils.someFunction(new Parameter().setParam16(2).setParam9(5).setParam19('Hello World'));
```

This can reduce the `SomeClass` complexity, and large functions that can have an arbitrarily large number of parameters can be reduced to a far more readable form. This also essentially lets us have named parameters, much like Ruby, C#, and other advanced languages.

However, you shouldn't use this *everywhere*. Use chaining when it makes sense, but don't return values that will never be used. This only clutters your code and makes it more confusing in the long run, and does marginally increase CPU usage (it's faster to not return a value at all than it is to return a chainable object).

As @KeithC pointed out by way of the link ([Builder Pattern: Good for code, great for tests](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/builder-pattern-good-for-code-great-for-tests.html)), this also lets you build objects that have a ton of default values but can then be customized. The code mentioned there is Java, but also easily applies to Apex Code as well. In fact, I'll borrow one of their examples to demonstrate:

```
Account account = new AccountBuilder()
                      .withId(1)
                      .withName("test")
                      .withBalance(10)
                      .build();
```

Using builders lets you set a bunch of default values (maybe record types, required fields, etc), as well as providing customization. In fact, this `AccountBuilder` class could easily be a legitimate piece of Apex Code. You could easily build records for unit tests with default values, and customize each account to a specific unit test. Of course, these exact functions may not make sense in your organization's case, but it demonstrates how you could build standard records with default values and optional customizations.

Comment: Hilarious example of parameterization. You have captured many of the use cases I dig it out for. It just seems borderline irresponsible to not return `this` for some of the system methods out there, for example `List.addAll`.

Comment: Worth mentioning: [Builder Pattern: Good for code, great for tests](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/builder-pattern-good-for-code-great-for-tests.html).

Comment: @AdrianLarson I'd be the first person so jump for joy if all those functions were suddenly useful. In fact, if we had the ability to write template classes, I'd have given up on the system collections a long time ago.

Comment: Some day...a man can dream!

Comment: +1 for the Builder Pattern example which is much better than the way I've been setting up test objects using a home-grown descriptor approach.

Answer (score 26):

I'll play devil's advocate with some reasons you might not want to chain methods. (I'm not necessarily saying a fluent interface is a bad thing, just providing some counter points.)

## Debugging and error handling

```
Utils.someFunction(new Parameter().setParam9(someVariable).setParam16(anotherVariable).setParam19(weDontHardCodeParametersWhereIComeFrom));
```

Quick, which part of that line just threw a `System.NullPointerException`? If you are lucky you might get an accurate column reference. More likely you will only have a line number.

If you could, say, set an actual breakpoint, how would you indicate which part of that line you wanted to stop on? You would either need to set the breakpoint within the method of interest, or painfully step through/over each chained method until you got to the one you want.

Last time I checked, the code coverage functionality in Salesforce only worked by the line rather than the statement. It wouldn't be possible to distinguish what is happening in that line.

## Potentially Long lines of code

So there are 32 optional parameters. What happens on the day when someone needs to set all of them?!

```
Utils.someFunction(new Parameter().setParam1(5).setParam2(2).setParam3('Hello World').setParam4('Help').setParam5(6).setParam6('Make').setParam7('the').setParam8('maddness').setParam9('Stop!').setParam10('It').setParam11('Hurts!').setParam12('My').setParam13('eyes!').setParam14('Hello World').setParam15('Hello World').setParam16('Hello World').setParam17('Hello World').setParam18('Hello World').setParam19('Hello World').setParam20('Hello World').setParam21('Hello World').setParam22('Hello World').setParam23('Hello World').setParam24('Hello World').setParam25('Hello World').setParam26('Hello World').setParam27('Hello World').setParam28('Hello World').setParam29('Hello World').setParam30('Hello World').setParam31('Hello World').setParam32('Sob') );
```

Or if you split one method per line:

```
Utils.someFunction(
    new Parameter()
        .setParam1(5)
        .setParam2(2)
        .setParam3('Hello World')
        .setParam4('Help')
        .setParam5(6)
        .setParam6('Make')
        .setParam7('the')
        .setParam8('madness')
        .setParam8('stop!')
        ...
        .setParam32('Sob') );
```

Now we have one apex code statement spanning 30+ lines. This comes back to the first point about debugging and error handling.

<strike>Also, you can't put comments in for individual method calls right next to the method.</strike> As per discussion with sfdcfox in the SFSE comments, it is possible to have Apex comments mid statement.

## Do you have an object in a consistent/valid state?

If you only provide constructors for an object that will create the instance in a consistent state then it will be much harder for others (or your future self) to muck it up. After the constructor completes, the object will be ready to use; no further initialization is required to set optional properties.

Whereas, with a chained factory, how do you know which methods you need to call to get a valid Account?

```
Account account = new AccountBuilder()
                  .build();
```

> BoomException: Account can't build as it doesn't have Id, Name or Amount set!

## Chaining should be restricted to the original object type

You don't want to chain from one object type to another. It would break the ability to chain further expected methods and it isn't apparent when the object type changes.

---

See also: [Method chaining - why is it a good practice, or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1103985/54026)

Some quotes from there:

> The point is - in 99% cases you can probably do just as well or even better without method chaining. But there is the 1% where this is the best approach. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1104078/54026)
>
> I think it's generally good practice to always write very short and concise lines. Every line should just make one method call. Prefer more lines to longer lines. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4039611/54026)
>
> The biggest problem for Method Chaining is the finishing problem. While there are workarounds, usually if you run into this you're better off usng a Nested Function. Nested Function is also a better choice if you are getting into a mess with Context Variables. [Source - Martin Fowler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1104138/54026)

Comment: One nitpick, you can multi-line the chaining.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Do you mean split the chain? Do several calls on one line, then several on the next?

Comment: Hard to comment but basically `new MyClass()\n\t.someMethod();`

Comment: @DanielBallinger One method call per line (see sfdcfox's AccountBuilder example) is a good way format in my view.

Comment: @AdrianLarson So visually a developer would see one chained method call per line, that will help readability to a degree. Doesn't Apex still see only one line of code?
Now we could have one apex code statement spanning 32 lines.

Comment: You are correct. Everything until `;`.

Comment: BTW, just want to double clarify that I'm not anti-method chaining. Just playing the devil's advocate role.

Comment: "Also, you can't put comments in for individual method calls right next to the method." -- Sure you can. Normal line and block comments can be interspersed throughout the chain.

Comment: +1 though for one very true point: debugging within a single line of code (chain or just really big if/do/while conditions, etc) is a royal pain in Apex Code. It's not unique to method chains, but it certainly is something to think about before combining arbitrarily long chains.

Comment: @sfdcfox I just tried with // and /* */ style comments mid statement. Neither worked for me in anonymous Apex. Maybe I have the syntax slightly off.

Comment: Salesforce can be funny! Ha! Nice work guys.

Comment: @DanielBallinger You need spaces, too. Here's an example I wrote in my dev org: `new A().b() /* multiline comment */ .c().d() // EOL comment...♪ .e();`

Comment: @sfdcfox Ah, good to know. Got that working now. I've updated my answer as such.