# Apex - return this

Tags: apex, design-patterns

I came across the following code. Is there any reason why it has used used `return this`?

```
public class EmailUtil {
       private Messaging.SingleEmailMessage singleEmailMessage;
       private final List<String> toAddresses;

       //optional parameters set to default        
       private String subject = '';
       private String htmlBody = ''; 
       private Boolean useSignature = false;
       private List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment> fileAttachments = null;
       //defaults to current user's first name + last name
       private String senderDisplayName = UserInfo.getFirstName()+' '+UserInfo.getLastName();
       //get the current user in context
       User currentUser = [Select email from User where username = :UserInfo.getUserName() limit 1];        
       //replyTo defaults to current user's email 
       private String replyTo = currentUser.email;
       private String plainTextBody = '';

       public EmailUtil(List<String> addresses) {
           this.toAddresses = addresses;
       }

       public EmailUtil senderDisplayName(String val) {
           senderDisplayName = val;
           return this;
       }

       public EmailUtil subject(String val) {
           subject = val;
           return this;
       }

       public EmailUtil htmlBody(String val) {
           htmlBody = val;
           return this;
       }

       public EmailUtil useSignature(Boolean bool) {
           useSignature = bool;
           return this;
       }

       public EmailUtil replyTo(String val) {
           replyTo = val;
           return this;
       }

       public EmailUtil plainTextBody(String val) {
           plainTextBody = val;
           return this;
       }

       public EmailUtil fileAttachments(List<Messaging.Emailfileattachment> val) {
           fileAttachments = val;
           return this;
       }

       //where it all comes together
       //this method is private and is called from sendEmail()
       private EmailUtil build() {
           singleEmailMessage = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
           singleEmailMessage.setToAddresses(this.toAddresses);
           singleEmailMessage.setSenderDisplayName(this.senderDisplayName);
           singleEmailMessage.setSubject(this.subject);
           singleEmailMessage.setHtmlBody(this.htmlBody);
           singleEmailMessage.setUseSignature(this.useSignature);
           singleEmailMessage.setReplyTo(this.replyTo);
           singleEmailMessage.setPlainTextBody(this.plainTextBody);
           singleEmailMessage.setFileAttachments(this.fileAttachments);
           return this;
       }

       //send the email message
       public void sendEmail() {
              try {
                  //call build first to create the email message object
                  build();
                  Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { singleEmailMessage });
              } catch (Exception ex) {
                  throw new GenericException('There was a problem while calling Messaging.sendEmail()');
              }                
       }    

   }
```

Source : http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/email-utility-class

Comment: I don't see any reason why that's useful to return this. I think that's probably really bad design. All these methods should be void.

Comment: I agree, I do not see any reason. Can you give an  example where return this is useful?

Comment: [Method chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) - Its a design pattern for a specific type of problem!

Comment: I don't see any problem when calling each method on a new line. That's just developer laziness :D

Comment: @MartinLezer Note the link Rahul gave. It's to solve a SPECIFIC type of problem. Note that these are private variables with no setters or getters. VOID methods wouldn't do what you'd expect them to do since the variables haven't been declared as apex properties.

Comment: @crmprogdev Void methods will work. These methods are just setting private variables depending on the param received. Then the build method use these private variables to instanciate a SingleEmailMessage class.

Comment: See also http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/115026/2995. You can use it anywhere the method would normally be void.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This way you can call your methods "as a flow" to generate an object:

```
EmailUtil email = new EmailUtil(new String[] {})
  .subject('My subject')
  .htmlBody('my body')
  .senderDisplayName('My name');
```

Because you return the current object with `this` you can access it and its methods/attributes.

I personally like this way to do.

Comment: Wow I never thought of that. That's great. What about performance? Is there any impact possible?

Comment: Performances are the ~same (depending of the use case)

Comment: Ok I will try some tests with this class :D See you in 2 hours.

Comment: @MartinLezer Some food for though: [premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization).

Comment: @MartinLezer Glad you took a look at that material. I'm 100% for only making changes that improve code and if method chaining doesn't work in your situation (or taste) don't use it. Think your 1 second difference is probably a false conclusion: chaining versus referencing a local variable or static methods is going to be a very small difference.

Comment: @KeithC Yes you're right I was mistaking... This is why I removed my comment. There's no impact on performance with this class. But I still can't decide if I find this solution more readable.

Comment: A good use case for this pattern is (but is not on Salesforce) `HTTPRequest` setting.

It is more readable to do so: `HTTPRequest request = new HTTPRequest().setMethod('GET').setEndpoint('www.salesforce.com').setHeader('Xx', 'Yy').setTimeout(2000);`

Comment: @keith I think when we write widely used utilities, that falls in the 3%. Also, [we've been here before](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/115026/2995)

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yeah, perhaps you should add that link to this answer. If its widely used, then the code base will be cleaner (in my view at least) for the method chaining. Would only be in the 3% if commonly called inside big loops.

Answer (score 5):

It's called `Fluent Pattern`, and as already mentioned, it enables chaining. You can see it demonstrated in the Composite pattern in [Apex Design Patterns](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Design_Patterns).

It's worth reading the excellent answers on [Why Would I Not Enable Chaining?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/115026/2995) for a deeper dive into the impact, but it's incredibly useful for building data. For example, I use it in my [SObjectFactory](https://github.com/apexlarson/SObjectFactory) library to simplify specification of multiple fields.

```
List<Opportunity> records = new SObjectBuilder(Opportunity.sObjectType)
    .put (Opportunity.AccountId, SObjectFactory.provideGenericParent(Account.sObjectType))
    .put(Opportunity.CloseDate, Date.today())
    .count (Limits.getLimitQueries() + 1)
    .create().getRecords();
```